# Desktop icons rearrange spontaneously (Yosemite)

Tags: finder, imac, macos, desktop

I like to have all my desktop icons and shortcuts in very specific places. When I take a screenshot of the screen (for example) and it is saved to a file on the desktop, all the desktop icons arrange on the right of the screen by name and I have to move all my icons back to where they were.

I have my desktop set to "none" sorting and "snap to grid" turned off so I can always keep my icons exactly where I want them all the time, without them moving around randomly whenever a file appears on the desktop.

Has anyone else experienced this? It's pretty annoying and very detrimental to the efficiency of my workflow, and others too, I'm sure.

iMac 21.5 inch, late 2012, OS X Yosemite 10.10

Comment: See if this helps... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151375/os-x-yosemite-desktop-icon-positioning-problems?rq=1

Comment: Tried the steps in your post and it appears to be behaving for now. I guess snapping to grid is more important than I thought. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome - give my solution an upvote next time you're passing :)

Comment: Yes, this problem persists. Especially frustrating, as I just rearranged the icons to their previous positions, took a break for dinner and... bam! Not sure what is going on, but there ought to be some sort of utility which allows for saving of desktop icon position state, and restoring to that state, when required...

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem.  If I tried to move an icon, it would bounce back.  The answer was so simple I couldn't believe it.  I went into "View" and clicked on to Sort by "None".  Simple.  Problem solved.

Comment: Seems like that's what OP is doing, but it isn't working for him